# What can be the possibilities for page objects to throw errors while doing validation on forms?

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, functional-testing, pageobjects

Recently in an interview, I was asked the following question:
I am doing a validation in two web forms using Page Objects in Selenium such that second form is validated according to the first form. My page object throws error. What can be the possibilities?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This was asked on the phone. No screen was shared. If you are still unclear, the second form is filled and validated according to the first form but the error comes in page object. I gave numerous possibilities but he didn't sound convinced.

Comment: Also, the first form is calling the second form in this case

Comment: I think the question is way too vague.  I'd ask for clarification.